# Can custom object caching TTLs be configured in CloundFront via Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

Via the CloudFront UI, I have the option to select "Customize" for "Object Caching", and then specify values for Minimum, Maximum, and Default TTL: [image: options]

However, I do not see support for anything other than MinimumTTL in the CloudFormation [CacheBehavior property type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachebehavior.html).

Am I missing something or is this just not supported via CloudFormation?

Comment: The min/max/default options are a [recent enhancement to CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudfront-update-configurable-max-and-default-ttl/).  Cloudformation usually seems to take a little while to implement new options in the underlying services, so it might be the case that is can't do it *yet*.

Comment: ugh..thanks. Guess I need to test and see if cloudformation updates will blow away those manual changes. Those settings are kind of critical to prevent caching an index.html page, unless there is some other way I don't know of.

Comment: Well, the way to prevent caching of a page is to send proper headers from your origin server, something along the line of `Cache-Control: no-cache` or a variant, such as `no-store` or `private`.    That's really more correct than using the CloudFront TTL settings, at any rate.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: It's pointed at an s3 bucket. I guess I could do it in a meta tag on the actual object?

Comment: Yes, the `Cache-Control` header you send when creating the object (or set on the object in the S3 console or by modifying the object later) is returned each time the object is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael-sqlbot noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872631/can-custom-object-caching-ttls-be-configured-in-cloundfront-via-cloudformation#comment53588185_32872631), the custom object caching TTL feature was a recent feature at the time, announced on [17 Jun 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudfront-update-configurable-max-and-default-ttl/) (just months before this question was originally asked). There is typically a lag between new AWS features and updated CloudFormation resource support for the feature.

On [28 Dec 2015](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html), AWS eventually added CloudFormation support for this feature to the [`CacheBehavior` property type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachebehavior.html) via the [`MaxTTL`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-cachebehavior-maxttl) and [`DefaultTTL`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-cachebehavior-defaultttl) properties.